# Strengthening of FLT

Tags: number-theory, terminology, diophantine-equations, conjectures

FLT is that there are no positive nontrivial integer solutions to the Diophantine equation $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for $n>2$. What about the conjecture that there are no nontrivial solutions to the DE $a^n + b^n = c^n + d^n$ for $n>4$; is there an explicit name for it? I know that it’s a case of Lander, Parkin, Selfridge, but does this particular case have its own name? It’s so natural that it must have its own name, one would figure.

Comment: What about $a=c$ and $b=d$? May be you want to refer to "non-trivial solutions".

Comment: You’re totally right my bad I’ll edit it.

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate is the same as this question; this question asks for a name

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Please be patient.  The dupe now has the name  [Lander, Parkin, Selfridge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture) case $(n,2,2).\,$ There's no need to have a new (terminology) question for each each parameter (these obfucate search results which usually are not for terminology).  If someone finds other names in common use then simple update the dupe).

Comment: I just want to know if it has a formal name that’s all like FLT is the formal name for (n,2,1)

Comment: I don't recall such but if someone finds one they can update the dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque Improving search results should be secondary to actually getting answers to questions. Consider that as things stand, nobody who comes across the older question would think that it's looking for a formal name for the equation!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Improving search results is *essential* - else thirteen years of effort by this community has gone to waste. It doesn't matter that the old question wasn't asking for a name. Rather what matters is that those searching for a name will now be able to find it there by an easy search.